# react native android release apk navigation error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, release-apk

```
 const OnSignInPressed = async () => {
            const formData={email,password}
            const res = await loginUser(formData);
            // await storeToken(res.data.token)
            ConstantId.accessToken = res.data.token;
                console.log("logtoken",res.data.token)
                navigation.navigate(HomeScreen);     
          }
```

i am able to move to home screen after hitting signin in debug mode but in release apk i installed on my phone i am able to log the token from so the response from backend is perfect the only problem is i am unable to navigate to homescreen

Comment: the value inside navigate should be string (the name of screen) not its self

Comment: Dhanyavaad , fixed it. so givjng screen name works in debug mode but not in the release , i didn't noticed it because all the time it worked perfectly in debug mode when developing